Trying to sort with getopts with different commands and cannot sort by price
I  am trying to sort an inventory list in unix/linux below. I am successful in sorting by name and ID and able to pull up the usage menu but cannot sort by price, even with an "awk" function.
I call the code with ./invOpt -p and the output continues to tell me it's an invalid option: -p then pulls up the usage menu below. I'm confused because it refuses to sort the 4th field where the price is. I don't know if the $ and/or the comma sign is messing up the sorting
"Usage: invOpts -i | -n | -p | -h
"  -i  sort by product ID"
"  -n  sort by product name"
"  -p  sort by price"
"  -h  display usage"

INVENTORY MENU:
Product ID   Product Name                   Quantity   Price        Total Value
-----------  ------------------------------ --------   -----        -----------
P101        Apple MacBook Pro           25      $2,399.99       $59,999.75
P102        Samsung Galaxy S23          40      $799.99         $31,999.60
P103        Apple iPhone 15             60      $999.99         $59,999.40
P104        Google Pixel 8              35      $899.99         $31,499.65
P105        Microsoft Surface Pro 9     18      $1,299.99       $23,399.82
P106        Dell XPS 13                 50      $1,099.99       $54,999.50
P107        Apple iPad Air              75      $599.99         $44,999.25
P108        Fitbit Charge 5             100     $179.95         $17,995.00
P109        Amazon Echo Dot 5th Gen     150     $49.99          $7,498.50
P110        Sonos One SL                80      $199.99         $15,999.20
P111        Logitech MX Master 3        120     $99.99          $11,998.80
P112        HP Spectre x360             25      $1,499.99       $37,499.75
P113        GoPro Hero 11               60      $399.99         $23,999.40
P114        Nintendo Switch OLED        45      $349.99         $15,749.55
P115        Canon EOS R6                15      $2,499.99       $37,499.85
P116        Seagate 2TB External Hard Drive 200     $69.99          $13,998.00
P117        Apple AirPods Pro 2nd Gen   130     $249.99         $32,498.70
P118        MSI GeForce RTX 4070        40      $599.99         $23,999.60
P119        Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon   20      $1,799.99       $35,999.80
P120        Anker PowerCore 26800       180     $59.99          $10,798.20

CURRENT CODE:
#!/bin/bash

# Function to display usage information
usage() {
    echo "Usage: invOpts -i | -n | -p | -h"
    echo "  -i  sort by product ID"
    echo "  -n  sort by product name"
    echo "  -p  sort by price"
    echo "  -h  display usage"
}

# Process command-line options using getopts
while getopts ":inp:h" opt; do
    case $opt in
        i)
            # Sort by product ID (Field 1) and save to a temp file
            tempFile="/tmp/inventory_sorted_by_id_$$.txt"
            sort -t: -k1,1 ~/A09/inventory > "$tempFile"
            ;;
        n)
            # Sort by product name (Field 2) and save to a temp file
            tempFile="/tmp/inventory_sorted_by_name_$$.txt"
            sort -t: -k2,2 ~/A09/inventory > "$tempFile"
            ;;
        p)
            # Sort by price (Field 4) and save to a temp file
            tempFile="/tmp/inventory_sorted_by_price_$$.txt"
            sort -t: -k4,4n ~/A09/inventory > "$tempFile"
            ;;
        h)
            # Display usage and exit
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        ?)
            # Handle invalid options
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

# If no option is provided, default to original file
if [[ -z $tempFile ]]; then
    tempFile=~/A09/inventory
fi

# Source the myFunctions script to use the chkFile function
source ~/Homework9/myFunctions

# Store the inventory file name
filename=~/A09/inventory

# Check if the file exists using chkFile
chkFile $filename
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Error: Inventory file does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Print the header
printf "%-12s %-30s %-10s %-15s %-15s\n" "Product ID" "Product Name" "Quantity" "Price" "Total Value"
printf "%-12s %-30s %-10s %-15s %-15s\n" "-----------" "------------------------------" "--------" "-----" "-----------"

# Initialize total inventory value
totalInventoryValue=0

# Read the sorted file line by line (either sorted or original)
while IFS=: read -r productID productName quantity price; do
    # Calculate the total value: Quantity * Price
    totalValue=$(echo "$quantity * $price" | bc -l)

    # Format the price and total value with commas
    formattedPrice=$(echo $price | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta')
    formattedTotalValue=$(echo $totalValue | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta')

    # Print the formatted data
    printf "%-12s %-30s %-10s $%-14s $%-14s\n" "$productID" "$productName" "$quantity" "$formattedPrice" "$formattedTotalValue"

    # Add total value to the overall inventory value
    totalInventoryValue=$(echo "$totalInventoryValue + $totalValue" | bc -l)
done < "$tempFile"

# Format the total inventory value with commas
formattedTotalInventoryValue=$(echo $totalInventoryValue | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta')

# Print the total inventory value
printf "\nTotal Inventory Value: $%-14s\n" "$formattedTotalInventoryValue"

# Clean up the temporary file
rm -f "$tempFile"


First thing, -p is defined to expect an argument but you don't use one in the corresponding case code. How do you call the code? (Please update your question to show how you'd use it to process some example input, and then also provide the expected corresponding output)

You're hitting this behavior (from output of help getopts):

If a required argument is not found, getopts places a ':' into NAME and sets OPTARG to the option character found.

When you write:
./invOpt -p

You are missing a requirement argument, because you have defined the -p option as p: in your call to getopts:
while getopts ":inp:h" opt; do

So when you write -p with no following argument, opt gets set to :. Because you don't have an explicit handler for this case, it ends up hitting your default case:
        ?)
            # Handle invalid options
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;

And that's why you get the "invalid option" error. It doesn't look like your code actually expects a value for the -p option, so the simplest solution is to rewrite your getopts call like this:
while getopts ":inph" opt; do

